# Getting errors like "Open Transition Assigned~Deferred to complete at least one Reason" while saving workitem in "TFS 2010".

Tags: tfs

Getting errors like "Open Transition Assigned~Deferred to complete at least one Reason" while saving 'bug' type workitem in "TFS 2010". Anyone plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Transaction and click on `Open Details`.

[image]

Now select the `Reasons tab` and type in `at least one reason` and then click OK.

[image]